# Create a polynomial with given zeros

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

Find a polynomial $()$ of degree 5 with zeros $3i, 1+ i$ and $2$ that satisfies $(0) = −18$ . Do not need
to multiply it out

A problem like this is simple, start with $p(x)=(x-3i)(x-(1+i))(x-2)$ . Now I’m assuming these are the only zeros we’re allowed to have, and we must have a degree of 5. So two of these must be squared. But there is no way to combine these to get $p(0)=-18$. I feel like there’s a mistake in the problem.

Here’s another approach $|-3i|=3, |-1-i|=\sqrt 2 $, and $|2|=2$. It’s impossible to combine $\sqrt 2, 2,$ and $3 $to get $-18$

Comment: You can also multiply the whole thing by a constant, for instance $100(x-3i)\cdots$.

Comment: But you wouldn’t get that degree of 5. Unless you randomly get a degree of 5, and then multiply by a constant fraction to reduce it to -18?

Comment: I'm just trying to extend your solution. You say you got to the point where you can obtain a polynomial of degree 5, with the correct roots, but not satisfying $p(0)=-18$. Well, then multiply it by a good constant.

Comment: If you want real coefficients, then assume you have 2 other solutions, 1 - i, and -3i. Then you will get a nice degree 5 equation with real coefficients. Multiply if necessary to get p(0)=18.

Answer (score 1):

You can have $$p(x)=\frac{i}{2}(x-3i)^2(x-(1+i))^2(x-2)$$

But this is a complex polynomial. It doesn't mention that these are the only zeros you are allowed to have, so we can use the complex conjugates to obtain $$p(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-3i)(x+3i)(x-(1+i))(x-(1-i))(x-2).$$

This gives a degree $5$ polynomial with real coefficients that satisfies $p(0)=-18.$